# Android Activity not starting in onTouch function

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I want to start an activity in the onTouch function but it is just showing me a blank screen. I have tested this activity and it runs when started from the main activity. Here i want to start this activity from a class which implements onTouchListener and also uses a custom view which extends from SurfaceView.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.tutorialfour;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    ourView v;
    Bitmap ball;
    Bitmap blue;
    Bitmap magenta;
    Bitmap yellow;
    Bitmap green;
    Bitmap red;
    Bitmap sp;
    float x,y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            v=new ourView(this);
            v.setOnTouchListener(this);
            ball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.search);
            blue=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue);
            magenta=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.magenta);
            yellow=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yellow);
            green=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green);
            red=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            sp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spouses);
            x=0;
            y=0;

            setContentView(v);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    float x1=0;
    float y1=0;
    float r=100;
    float tlx=100;  //top left x
    float tly=100;  //top left y
    float trx;
    float try1;
    float dlx;
    float dly;
    float drx;
    float dry;
    float aux;      //action up x
    float auy;
    float cw;
    float ch;
    int distance;
    String predecessor = "Hello world of programming. Hello world of programming";
    String successor =  "Hello world of programming. Hello world of programming";
    String father = "Hello world of programming. Hello world of programming";
    String mother =  "";
    String spouses =  "Hello world of programming. Hello world of programming";
    int check=0;
    Bitmap scaled;
    String first="";
    String second= "";
    String third = "";
    boolean pred = true;
    boolean succ = true;
    boolean fath = true;
    boolean moth = true;
    boolean spou = true;
    float spx=3000;
    float spy=3000;
    int k=0;
    float aspx,aspy;
    boolean spGo=false;
    boolean spr=true, sps=true,spf=true,spm=true;
    Canvas c;
    Context context1;
    public class ourView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {
        Thread t=null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean IsItOK=false;

        public ourView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            context1=context;
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(IsItOK=true)
            {
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                //c.drawBitmap(ball, 0, 0, null);

                if(check==0)
                {
                int canvasWidth = c.getWidth();
                int canvasHeight = c.getHeight();

                int imageWidth = ball.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = ball.getHeight();

                float scaleFactor = Math.max( (float)canvasWidth / imageWidth, 
                                              (float)canvasHeight / imageHeight );
                scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(  ball, 
                                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageWidth), 
                                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageHeight), 
                                                            true );
                check++;
                }

                c.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setTextSize(24);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                Paint paint1 = new Paint();
                paint1.setTextSize(24);
                paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                paint1.setAntiAlias(true);


//left-top              
                if(!(predecessor.length()==0))
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    c.drawBitmap(magenta, x1, y1, null);
                    //c.drawCircle(x1+r, y1+r, r, paint1);
                    if(pred==true)
                    {
                        adjustText(predecessor);
                        pred= false;
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(first.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(first, x1+20, y1+((r/2)+10), paint);
                    }
                    if(second.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(second, x1+3, y1+r, paint);
                    }
                    if(third.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(third, x1+20, y1+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                    }

                }

                c.drawBitmap(red, x1+((c.getWidth()/2)-(r+(r/2))), y1+((c.getHeight()/2)-(r+(r/2))), null);
                //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()/2), y1+(c.getHeight()/2), r+(r/2), new Paint());//center
//down right                
                if(!(mother.length()==0))
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()-r), y1+(c.getHeight()-r), r, paint1);
                    c.drawBitmap(green, x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)), y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2)), null);

                    if(moth==true)
                    {
                        adjustText(mother);
                        moth= false;
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(first.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(first, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, (y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r/2)+10), paint);
                    }
                    if(second.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(second, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+3, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+r, paint);
                    }
                    if(third.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(third, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                    }

                }


                drx = x1+(c.getWidth()-r);
                dry = y1+(c.getHeight()-r);




//top right             
                if(!(successor.length()==0))
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    c.drawBitmap(yellow, x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)), y1, null);
                    //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()-r), y1+r, r, paint1);
                    if(succ==true)
                    {
                        adjustText(successor);
                        succ= false;
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(first.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(first, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, (y1+(r/2)+10), paint);
                    }
                    if(second.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(second, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+3, y1+r, paint);
                    }
                    if(third.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(third, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, y1+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                    }

                }




                trx = x1+(c.getWidth()-r);
                try1 = y1+r;
//down left             
                if(!(father.length()==0))
                {
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    c.drawBitmap(blue, x1, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2)), null);
                    //c.drawCircle(x1+r, y1+(c.getHeight()-r), r, paint1);
                    if(fath==true)
                    {
                        adjustText(father);
                        fath= false;
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(first.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(first, x1+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+((r/2)+10), paint);
                    }
                    if(second.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(second, x1+3, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+r, paint);
                    }
                    if(third.length()!=0)
                    {
                        c.drawText(third, x1+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                    }

                }



                dlx = x1+r;
                dly=y1+(c.getHeight()-r);

                cw= c.getWidth();
                ch=c.getHeight();
//Spouses Circle on the front screen if some circle is missing which is identified by k     
                if(k<=3)
                {

                    if(pred==true)
                    {
                        spx=x1;
                        spy=y1;
                        spr=false;
                    }
                    else if(succ==true)
                    {
                        spx=x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)); 
                        spy=y1;

                        sps=false;
                    }
                    else if(fath==true)
                    {
                        spx=x1;
                        spy=y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2));
                        spf=false;
                    }
                    else if(moth==true)
                    {
                        spx=x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)); 
                        spy=y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2));
                        spm=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        spx=2000;
                        spy=2000;
                    }

                    if(!(spouses.length()==0))
                    {
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        c.drawBitmap(sp, spx, spy, null);
                        //c.drawCircle(x1+r, y1+(c.getHeight()-r), r, paint1);
                        if(spou==true)
                        {
                            //adjustText(spouses);
                            spou= false;
                            //k++;
                        }
                        c.drawText("Show Spouses", spx+20, spy+r+5, paint);

                    }
                }


                //Log.e(mother+cw, "\n"+mother+ch);

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }
        public void pause()
        {
            IsItOK=false;
            while(true)
            {
                try{
                    t.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            }
            t=null;
        }
        public void resume()
        {
            IsItOK=true;
            t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch(me.getAction())
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                aux=me.getX();
                auy=me.getY();

                break;
    /*      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x=me.getX();
                y=me.getY();
                break;
        */}



        if((aux>=0 && aux<=(r*2)) && (auy>=0 && auy<=(r*2)) || spr==false)
        {
            if(!(tlx==0 || tly==0))
                distance = getDistance(tlx,tly);
            if(spr==false)
                spGo=true;
        }
        else if((aux>=(cw-(r*2)) && aux<=cw) && (auy>=0 && auy<=(r*2)) || sps==false)
        {
            if(!(trx==0 || try1==0))
                distance = getDistance(trx,try1);
            if(sps==false)
                spGo=true;
        }
        else if((aux>=0 && aux<=(r*2)) && (auy>=(ch-(r*2)) && auy<=ch) || spf==false)
        {
            if(!(dlx==0 || dly==0))
                distance = getDistance(dlx,dly);
            if(spf==false)
                spGo=true;
        }

        else if((aux>=(cw-(r*2)) && aux<=cw) && (auy>=(ch-(r*2)) && auy<=ch) || spm==false)
        {
            if(!(drx==0 || dry==0))
                distance = getDistance(drx,dry);
            if(spm==false)
                spGo=true;
        }
        else
        {

        }


        if(distance>r)
        {
        }
        else if(spGo==true)
        {
            try{
                //v.destroyDrawingCache();
                //Log.e(mother+cw, "\n"+mother+ch);
                v.clearAnimation();
                c.restore();

    //          Intent first = new Intent("com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES");

        //      SurfaceViewExample.this.startActivity(first);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES");
                //myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                SurfaceViewExample.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
        else
        {
            DrawingTheBall d = new DrawingTheBall(this);
            setContentView(d);

        }

        return true;
    }

    public int getDistance(float x2,float y2)
    {
        distance = (int) Math.sqrt(((aux-x2)*(aux-x2))+((auy-y2)*(auy-y2)));
        return distance;
    }
    public void adjustText(String str)
    {
        if(str.length()>13)
        {
            first = str.substring(0, 14);
            str = str.substring(14, str.length());
            if(str.length()>15)
            {
                second = str.substring(0, 16);
                str = str.substring(16, str.length());
                if(str.length()>13)
                {
                    third = str.substring(0, 13);
                    third+="...";
                    str = str.substring(13, str.length());

                }
                else
                {
                    third = str;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                second = str;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            first = str;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code which i am using in onTouch function:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES");
SurfaceViewExample.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Please help me, i have tried many solutions available on internet but none of them work.

Update: Here is the manifest entry of activity:

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.example.tutorialfour.drawSpouses" 
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Update: drawSpouses's code:

```
package com.example.tutorialfour;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;


public class drawSpouses extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    spouseView v;
    Bitmap sp;
    Bitmap ball;
    Bitmap red;
    float x,y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            v=new spouseView(this);
            v.setOnTouchListener(this);
            ball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.search);
            sp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spouses);
            red=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            x=0;
            y=0;
            setContentView(v);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    float x1=0;
    float y1=0;
    float r=100;
    float tlx=100;  //top left x
    float tly=100;  //top left y
    float trx;
    float try1;
    float dlx;
    float dly;
    float drx;
    float dry;
    float aux;      //action up x
    float auy;
    float cw;
    float ch;
    int distance;
    String spouses =  "Hello world of programming. Hello world of programming";
    int check=0;
    Bitmap scaled;
    String first="";
    String second= "";
    String third = "";
    boolean pred = true;
    boolean succ = true;
    boolean fath = true;
    boolean moth = true;
    boolean spou = true;
    float spx=3000;
    float spy=3000;
    int k=0;
    String c1="", c2="", c3 ="", c4="";
    public class spouseView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {
        Thread t=null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean IsItOK=false;

        public spouseView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(IsItOK=true)
            {
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                //c.drawBitmap(ball, 0, 0, null);

                if(check==0)
                {
                int canvasWidth = c.getWidth();
                int canvasHeight = c.getHeight();

                int imageWidth = ball.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = ball.getHeight();

                float scaleFactor = Math.max( (float)canvasWidth / imageWidth, 
                                              (float)canvasHeight / imageHeight );
                scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(  ball, 
                                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageWidth), 
                                                            (int)(scaleFactor * imageHeight), 
                                                            true );
                check++;
                }

                c.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setTextSize(24);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                Paint paint1 = new Paint();
                paint1.setTextSize(24);
                paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                paint1.setAntiAlias(true);


//left-top              
                if(!(spouses.length()==0))
                {
                    if(spou==true)
                    {
                        adjustText(spouses);
                        spou=false;
                    }

                    if(!(c1.length()==0))
                    {
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        c.drawBitmap(sp, x1, y1, null);
                        //c.drawCircle(x1+r, y1+r, r, paint1);
                        if(pred==true)
                        {
                            divideText(c1);
                            pred= false;
                            k++;
                        }
                        if(first.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(first, x1+20, y1+((r/2)+10), paint);
                        }
                        if(second.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(second, x1+3, y1+r, paint);
                        }
                        if(third.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(third, x1+20, y1+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                        }
                    }


                    if(!(c2.length()==0))
                    {
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        c.drawBitmap(sp, x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)), y1, null);
                        //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()-r), y1+r, r, paint1);
                        if(succ==true)
                        {
                            divideText(c2);
                            succ= false;
                            k++;
                        }
                        if(first.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(first, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, (y1+(r/2)+10), paint);
                        }
                        if(second.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(second, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+3, y1+r, paint);
                        }
                        if(third.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(third, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, y1+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                        }

                    }

                    if(!(c3.length()==0))
                    {
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        c.drawBitmap(sp, x1, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2)), null);
                        //c.drawCircle(x1+r, y1+(c.getHeight()-r), r, paint1);
                        if(fath==true)
                        {
                            divideText(c3);
                            fath= false;
                            k++;
                        }
                        if(first.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(first, x1+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+((r/2)+10), paint);
                        }
                        if(second.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(second, x1+3, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+r, paint);
                        }
                        if(third.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(third, x1+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                        }

                    }
                    if(!(c4.length()==0))
                    {
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()-r), y1+(c.getHeight()-r), r, paint1);
                        c.drawBitmap(sp, x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)), y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2)), null);

                        if(moth==true)
                        {
                            divideText(c4);
                            moth= false;
                            k++;
                        }
                        if(first.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(first, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, (y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r/2)+10), paint);
                        }
                        if(second.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(second, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+3, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+r, paint);
                        }
                        if(third.length()!=0)
                        {
                            c.drawText(third, (x1+(c.getWidth()-(r*2)))+20, y1+(c.getHeight()-(r*2))+(r+(r/2)), paint);
                        }

                    }


                }

                c.drawBitmap(red, x1+((c.getWidth()/2)-(r+(r/2))), y1+((c.getHeight()/2)-(r+(r/2))), null);
                //c.drawCircle(x1+(c.getWidth()/2), y1+(c.getHeight()/2), r+(r/2), new Paint());//center
//down right                


                drx = x1+(c.getWidth()-r);
                dry = y1+(c.getHeight()-r);




//top right             





                trx = x1+(c.getWidth()-r);
                try1 = y1+r;
//down left             




                dlx = x1+r;
                dly=y1+(c.getHeight()-r);

                cw= c.getWidth();
                ch=c.getHeight();

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }
        public void pause()
        {
            IsItOK=false;
            while(true)
            {
                try{
                    t.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            }
            t=null;
        }
        public void resume()
        {
            IsItOK=true;
            t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switch(me.getAction())
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                aux=me.getX();
                auy=me.getY();

                break;
    /*      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x=me.getX();
                y=me.getY();
                break;
        */}



        if((aux>=0 && aux<=(r*2)) && (auy>=0 && auy<=(r*2)))
        {
            if(!(tlx==0 || tly==0))
                distance = getDistance(tlx,tly);
        }
        else if((aux>=(cw-(r*2)) && aux<=cw) && (auy>=0 && auy<=(r*2)))
        {
            if(!(trx==0 || try1==0))
                distance = getDistance(trx,try1);
        }
        else if((aux>=0 && aux<=(r*2)) && (auy>=(ch-(r*2)) && auy<=ch))
        {
            if(!(dlx==0 || dly==0))
                distance = getDistance(dlx,dly);
        }

        else if((aux>=(cw-(r*2)) && aux<=cw) && (auy>=(ch-(r*2)) && auy<=ch))
        {
            if(!(drx==0 || dry==0))
                distance = getDistance(drx,dry);
        }
        else
        {

        }


        if(distance>r)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DrawingTheBall d = new DrawingTheBall(this);
            setContentView(d);

        }

        return true;
    }
    public int getDistance(float x2,float y2)
    {
        distance = (int) Math.sqrt(((aux-x2)*(aux-x2))+((auy-y2)*(auy-y2)));
        return distance;
    }
    public void adjustText(String str)
    {
        int ind=0;
        if(str.contains("\n"))
        {
            ind= str.indexOf('\n');
            c1= str.substring(0, ind);
            str = str.substring(ind+1, str.length());
            if(str.contains("\n"))
            {
                ind= str.indexOf('\n');
                c2= str.substring(0, ind);
                str = str.substring(ind+1, str.length());
                if(str.contains("\n"))
                {
                    ind= str.indexOf('\n');
                    c3= str.substring(0, ind);
                    str = str.substring(ind+1, str.length());
                    if(str.contains("\n"))
                    {
                        ind= str.indexOf('\n');
                        c4= str.substring(0, ind);
                        str = str.substring(ind+1, str.length());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c4=str;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    c3=str;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                c2=str;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            c1 = str;
        }



    }
    public void divideText(String str)
    {
        if(str.length()>13)
        {
            first = str.substring(0, 14);
            str = str.substring(14, str.length());
            if(str.length()>15)
            {
                second = str.substring(0, 16);
                str = str.substring(16, str.length());
                if(str.length()>13)
                {
                    third = str.substring(0, 13);
                    third+="...";
                    str = str.substring(13, str.length());

                }
                else
                {
                    third = str;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                second = str;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            first = str;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why u put too much code

Comment: What is the problem when you are using the above code, are you getting any exception ?

Comment: please show us the manifest entry for `com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES` Activity...

Comment: @stackoverflow, sorry i just copied my complete class's code.

Comment: @Pragnani, No exception is raised. It just show me a blank screen

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar, I have updated my question with the activity entry in manifest file.

Comment: @user2184654 Post your DRAWSPOUSES Activity, if it show black screen mean intent is working

Comment: @Pragnani, I have added drawSpouses's code. Also this code runs fine when i call the same intent from MainActivity class. Please help me...

Comment: @user2184654 Your code seems to be ok.. Not sure but Try to call intent in `runonUIThread(Runnable)`

Comment: @Pragnani, Still not working. How can i pass intent as a parameter while it takes a Runnable as parameter?

Comment: @user2184654 Try my answer once

Comment: @Pragnani, No success. I can't add comments to the answer below.

Comment: @user2184654 finally try this `Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),drawSpouses.class);
               getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: @user2184654 Let me know, if it work for you

Comment: @Pragnani, It is showing me the following error: "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type SurfaceViewExample". I appreciate your help :) If nothing happens, please just add an answer whether working or not. I will definitely rate it the best :)

Comment: @Pragnani, Is there any other way?

Comment: @user2184654 Check my edit..And let me know if it work for you..

Comment: I have successfully started an intent by onTouch check it out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509749/multiple-intents-starting-by-ontouch-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Take a field context in your Activity like this

```
Context context;
```

and then set

```
 context=this;
```

in your `onCreate` of the Activity

Then call it like this

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,drawSpouses.class);     
     context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same results :( Can i start a simple activity from here instead of drawSpouses? i mean which don't extends SurfaceView or implements onTouchListener?

Comment: @user2184654 is there are exception in logcat..? and try calling any other Activity to check whether it is working or not

Comment: No there is no exception. I did but no other activity can be started.

Comment: try calling `startActivity(myIntent)` directly, with out context

Comment: Finally i got an exception. "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tutorialfour/com.example.tutorialfour.drawSpouses}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
"

Comment: @user2184654 ok then call it usual way using intent filter.  `Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.tutorialfour.DRAWSPOUSES");`

Comment: No, Still only blank Screen. Is there any way that i rate your answer but this question don't close?

Comment: @user2184654 No need...If it show the blank screen then, it is not the problem with intent as I have said earlier.. It was the problem with your second class `drawSpouses` place a debugger in it or call it directly from other classes to check whether it works for you are not

Comment: I have already called it directly from other classes and it works. I have changed one thing in the manifest file. I have added SurfaceViewExample as a LAUNCHER in manifest file instead of MainActivity. Do you think this can be the problem?

Comment: @user2184654 Try to place a log message or debugger to check whether you are navigating to other Activity. or Take a blank Activity as launcher and pass intent to drawSpouses Activity

Comment: I have taken a blank activity and pass drawSpouses as intents and it works fine. Do i need to close the previous view before shifting to other activity? because when blank screen comes, the application size in the taskManager of my tablet increases continuously and so is the CPU usage and then it closes the application.

Comment: @user2184654 I am not sure about that... But Have it a try. And also you'll get Exception when application closes, check logcat once

Comment: I did, there is no exception :(

Comment: I am rating your answer. Please if you find any solution, mail me at yola3467@gmail.com. I will be happy to add you in gmail as a friend :) You really tried to help :) Thanks a lot...